# Header file linker error

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I do not understand why I get the following error

```
fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

IDirect3DDevice10Hook.h:

```
#include "../graphics/includes.h"
#include "../hook/FW1FontWrapper.h"
#include "../hook/BeaEngine.h"

typedef HRESULT(__stdcall *D3D11PresentHook) (IDXGISwapChain* pSwapChain,    UINT SyncInterval, UINT Flags);
typedef void(__stdcall *D3D11DrawIndexedHook) (ID3D11DeviceContext* pContext, UINT IndexCount, UINT StartIndexLocation, INT BaseVertexLocation);
typedef void(__stdcall *D3D11ClearRenderTargetViewHook) (ID3D11DeviceContext* pContext, ID3D11RenderTargetView *pRenderTargetView, const FLOAT ColorRGBA[4]);

struct HookContext {
BYTE original_code[64];
SIZE_T dst_ptr;
BYTE far_jmp[6];
};

HookContext *presenthook64;
ID3D11Device *pDevice = NULL;
ID3D11DeviceContext *pContext = NULL;

DWORD_PTR* pSwapChainVtable = NULL;
DWORD_PTR* pDeviceContextVTable = NULL;

D3D11PresentHook phookD3D11Present = NULL;
D3D11DrawIndexedHook phookD3D11DrawIndexed = NULL;
D3D11ClearRenderTargetViewHook phookD3D11ClearRenderTargetView = NULL;

IFW1Factory *pFW1Factory = NULL;
IFW1FontWrapper *pFontWrapper = NULL;

bool firstTime = true;
void* detourBuffer[3];

HRESULT  hookD3D11Present(IDXGISwapChain* pSwapChain, UINT SyncInterval, UINT Flags);
void hookD3D11DrawIndexed(ID3D11DeviceContext *pContext, UINT IndexCount, UINT StartIndexLocation, INT BaseVertexLocation);
void  hookD3D11ClearRenderTargetView(ID3D11DeviceContext *pContext, ID3D11RenderTargetView *pRenderTargetView, const FLOAT ColorRGBA[4]);
const void* DetourFuncVTable(SIZE_T *src, const BYTE *dest, const DWORD index);
const unsigned int DisasmLengthCheck(const SIZE_T address, const unsigned int jumplength);
const void* DetourFunc64(BYTE* const src, const BYTE* dest, const unsigned int jumplength);
DWORD InitializeHook(LPVOID);
```

This is my header file, i have the IDirect3DDevice10Hook.cpp and i dont get code error, i created that function in header file beacuse i want use them in another file in my Solution.

But when i used the code in dllmain.cpp everything is fine and its work and i dont get error, this is my dllmain.cpp:

```
#include "../clientscript/core/graphics/includes.h"
#include "core\hook\FW1FontWrapper.h"
#include "core\hook\BeaEngine.h"

typedef HRESULT(__stdcall *D3D11PresentHook) (IDXGISwapChain* pSwapChain, UINT SyncInterval, UINT Flags);
typedef void(__stdcall *D3D11DrawIndexedHook) (ID3D11DeviceContext* pContext, UINT IndexCount, UINT StartIndexLocation, INT BaseVertexLocation);
typedef void(__stdcall *D3D11ClearRenderTargetViewHook) (ID3D11DeviceContext* pContext, ID3D11RenderTargetView *pRenderTargetView, const FLOAT ColorRGBA[4]);

struct HookContext {
BYTE original_code[64];
SIZE_T dst_ptr;
BYTE far_jmp[6];
};

HookContext *presenthook64;
ID3D11Device *pDevice = NULL;
ID3D11DeviceContext *pContext = NULL;

DWORD_PTR* pSwapChainVtable = NULL;
DWORD_PTR* pDeviceContextVTable = NULL;

D3D11PresentHook phookD3D11Present = NULL;
D3D11DrawIndexedHook phookD3D11DrawIndexed = NULL;
D3D11ClearRenderTargetViewHook phookD3D11ClearRenderTargetView = NULL;

IFW1Factory *pFW1Factory = NULL;
IFW1FontWrapper *pFontWrapper = NULL;

bool firstTime = true;
void* detourBuffer[3];

// hookD3D11Present*
HRESULT __stdcall hookD3D11Present(IDXGISwapChain* pSwapChain, UINT     SyncInterval, UINT Flags)
{
    if (firstTime)
    {
        pSwapChain->GetDevice(__uuidof(pDevice), (void**)&pDevice);
        pDevice->GetImmediateContext(&pContext);
        FW1CreateFactory(FW1_VERSION, &pFW1Factory);
        pFW1Factory->CreateFontWrapper(pDevice, L"Impact", &pFontWrapper);
        pFW1Factory->Release();
        firstTime = false;
     }
     pFontWrapper->DrawString(pContext, L"Test Test", 10.0f, 16.0f, 16.0f, 0xffff1612, FW1_RESTORESTATE);
     return phookD3D11Present(pSwapChain, SyncInterval, Flags);
}

// hookD3D11DrawIndexed*
void __stdcall hookD3D11DrawIndexed(ID3D11DeviceContext* pContext, UINT IndexCount, UINT StartIndexLocation, INT BaseVertexLocation)
{
    return phookD3D11DrawIndexed(pContext, IndexCount, StartIndexLocation, BaseVertexLocation);
}

// hookD3D11ClearRenderTargetView*
void __stdcall hookD3D11ClearRenderTargetView(ID3D11DeviceContext* pContext,      ID3D11RenderTargetView *pRenderTargetView, const FLOAT ColorRGBA[4])
{
return phookD3D11ClearRenderTargetView(pContext, pRenderTargetView, ColorRGBA);
}

// DetourFuncVTable*
const void* DetourFuncVTable(SIZE_T* src, const BYTE* dest, const DWORD index)
{
    DWORD dwVirtualProtectBackup;
    SIZE_T* const indexPtr = &src[index];
    const void* origFunc = (void*)*indexPtr;
    VirtualProtect(indexPtr, sizeof(SIZE_T), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwVirtualProtectBackup);
    *indexPtr = (SIZE_T)dest;
    VirtualProtect(indexPtr, sizeof(SIZE_T), dwVirtualProtectBackup, &dwVirtualProtectBackup);
    return origFunc;
 }

// DisasmLengthCheck*
const unsigned int DisasmLengthCheck(const SIZE_T address, const unsigned int jumplength)
{
    DISASM disasm;
    memset(&disasm, 0, sizeof(DISASM));
    disasm.EIP = (UIntPtr)address;
    disasm.Archi = 0x40;
    unsigned int processed = 0;
    while (processed < jumplength)
    {
        const int len = Disasm(&disasm);
        if (len == UNKNOWN_OPCODE) ++disasm.EIP;
        else
        {
            processed += len;
            disasm.EIP += len;
        }
    }
    return processed;
}

// DetourFunc64*
const void* DetourFunc64(BYTE* const src, const BYTE* dest, const unsigned int jumplength)
{
    // Allocate a memory page that is going to contain executable code.
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
    for (SIZE_T addr = (SIZE_T)src; addr > (SIZE_T)src - 0x80000000; addr = (SIZE_T)mbi.BaseAddress - 1)
    {
        if (!VirtualQuery((LPCVOID)addr, &mbi, sizeof(mbi))) break;
        if (mbi.State == MEM_FREE) if (presenthook64 =    (HookContext*)VirtualAlloc(mbi.BaseAddress, 0x1000, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE)) break;
    }
    // If allocating a memory page failed, the function failed.
    if (!presenthook64)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    // Select a pointer slot for the memory page to be freed on unload.
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(detourBuffer) / sizeof(void*); ++i)
    {
        if (!detourBuffer[i])
        {
            detourBuffer[i] = presenthook64;
            break;
        }
    }
    // Save original code and apply detour. The detour code is:
    BYTE detour[] = { 0x50, 0x48, 0xB8, 0xCC, 0xCC, 0xCC, 0xCC, 0xCC, 0xCC, 0xCC, 0xCC, 0x48, 0x87, 0x04, 0x24, 0xC3 };
    const unsigned int length = DisasmLengthCheck((SIZE_T)src, jumplength);
    memcpy(presenthook64->original_code, src, length);
    memcpy(&presenthook64->original_code[length], detour, sizeof(detour));
    *(SIZE_T*)&presenthook64->original_code[length + 3] = (SIZE_T)src + length;
    // Build a far jump to the destination function.
    *(WORD*)&presenthook64->far_jmp = 0x25FF;
    *(DWORD*)(presenthook64->far_jmp + 2) = (DWORD)((SIZE_T)presenthook64 - (SIZE_T)src + FIELD_OFFSET(HookContext, dst_ptr) - 6);
    presenthook64->dst_ptr = (SIZE_T)dest;
    // Write the hook to the original function.
    DWORD flOld = 0;
    VirtualProtect(src, 6, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &flOld);
    memcpy(src, presenthook64->far_jmp, sizeof(presenthook64->far_jmp));
    VirtualProtect(src, 6, flOld, &flOld);
    // Return a pointer to the original code.
    return presenthook64->original_code;
}

// InitializeHook*
DWORD __stdcall InitializeHook(LPVOID)
{
    HWND hWnd = GetForegroundWindow();
    IDXGISwapChain* pSwapChain;
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevel = D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0;
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC swapChainDesc;

    ZeroMemory(&swapChainDesc, sizeof(swapChainDesc));
    swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 1;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    swapChainDesc.OutputWindow = hWnd;
    swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    swapChainDesc.Windowed = TRUE;//((GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & WS_POPUP) != 0) ? FALSE : TRUE;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.ScanlineOrdering = DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_UNSPECIFIED;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Scaling = DXGI_MODE_SCALING_UNSPECIFIED;
    swapChainDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;

    D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, NULL, NULL, &featureLevel, 1, D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &swapChainDesc, &pSwapChain, &pDevice, NULL, &pContext);
    pSwapChainVtable = (DWORD_PTR*)pSwapChain;
    pSwapChainVtable = (DWORD_PTR*)pSwapChainVtable[0];
    pDeviceContextVTable = (DWORD_PTR*)pContext;
    pDeviceContextVTable = (DWORD_PTR*)pDeviceContextVTable[0];

    phookD3D11Present =  (D3D11PresentHook)DetourFunc64((BYTE*)pSwapChainVtable[8], (BYTE*)hookD3D11Present, 16);
    phookD3D11DrawIndexed = (D3D11DrawIndexedHook)DetourFunc64((BYTE*)pDeviceContextVTable[12], (BYTE*)hookD3D11DrawIndexed, 16);
    phookD3D11ClearRenderTargetView = (D3D11ClearRenderTargetViewHook)DetourFunc64((BYTE*)pDeviceContextVTable[50], (BYTE*)hookD3D11ClearRenderTargetView, 16);

    pDevice->Release();
    pContext->Release();
    pSwapChain->Release();
    return NULL;
}

BOOL __stdcall DllMain(HINSTANCE hModule, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (dwReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        {
            memset(detourBuffer, 0, sizeof(detourBuffer) * sizeof(void*));
            CreateThread(NULL, 0, InitializeHook, NULL, 0, NULL);
        }
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        {
            if (pFontWrapper) pFontWrapper->Release();
            for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(detourBuffer) / sizeof(void*); ++i) if (detourBuffer[i]) VirtualFree(detourBuffer[i], 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

how can i fix it?
my target is create the header file and use the functions in dllmain.cpp but i got this error, Thanks for helpers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *defined* variables in your header file. Of course you are getting linker errors, if the header is included into multiple translation units. Just like the linker told you, you are ending up with multiple definitions of the same variable.

Don't define variables in header files.

If you really need global variables, then the header file must contain non-defining variable declarations only, e.g.

```
extern ID3D11Device *pDevice;
```

Note: `extern` keyword is added, and initializer is removed. It is important to do both.

The definition (with initializer, if any) goes into the implementation file

```
ID3D11Device *pDevice = NULL;
```

Judging by what you posted so far, you already properly placed the definitions into the implementation file. All that's left to do is turn the definitions int the header into non-defining declarations by adding `extern` keyword and removing initializers.

Comment: Thanks for answer but its still give me the same error

Comment: @Dan: No it didn't. If you fix your variable declarations as shown above, the error will disappear. If the error is still there, then you either missed something, or the root of the problem is in something you are not showing us. From what you posted so far, the problem is *exactly* in what I stated above, period.

Comment: First of all Thanks for the help but i do what you told me and its still give me that error, Here my new files:

Header File: http://pastebin.com/7k5J7Hsu
Cpp File: http://pastebin.com/yFhuh7ZR

Comment: @Dan: In order to turn a variable definition into a mere declaration, you have to add `extern` keyword in the header file and **remove any variable initializers** from the header file. I'm pretty sure you simply forgot to do the latter part. Because of that your misplaced definitions in the header file remain definitions and the error persists.

Comment: Why this give me error? i do what you told me to do: http://pastebin.com/JT3c3n6r

Comment: @Dan: It is not possible to say why from what you posted so far. This specific header file looks fine now. What error are you getting again and what symbols are reported as multiply defined? Linker should tell you which specific symbols are causing the error.

Comment: It is strange that in dllmain it does not show me any error, why?

Comment: @Dan: Well, I cannot see from here what you are doing and how your files are organized. Are you files in different libraries? Or are they in the same library? As you can see the error is completely different now. And most likely it is caused by the fact that you are trying to use global DLL variables in main program, but you never exported these variables from DLL. If you want to use something from DLL in main program you have to *export* it from DLL. You have to consult your compiler documentation on how to export things from dynamic libraries.

Comment: Look I have a solution specific as you can see I just want to set the functions and use them in dllmain This is the same solution, I do not understand why I'm getting these errors, there is a way to define functions in dllmain as it works for a change and through dllmain use functions in other files I have in soultion? What can I do

Comment: @Dan: It is not about being in the same *solution*. It is about being in the same *project* in a solution. You already said above that everything works fine in `DllMain` (and it should). The error you posted are from `IDirect3DDevice10Hook.obj`, which is something completely different and, I suspect, from a completely different project. If it is from a different project, and if this project with `DllMain` is a DLL, then you will have to *export* these variables from DLL for them to become accessible in other projects. And that is a completely separate story.

Comment: I do not know what I can do should the problem be solved?
I tried to open a new project and still the same, I want to use the functions Total other files I do not care that they will be on the dllmain How can I do that there must be a way

Comment: @Dan: Of course, there is a way. As I said, I you want your DLL variables to become global and accessible *outside* of the DLL, you have to *export* them from DLL and *import* them into other modules. In MSVC it is done by using `__declspec(dllexport)` and `__declspec(dllimport)` directives.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could add some header guards:

```
#ifndef _IDIRECT3DDEVICE10HOOK_H_
#define _IDIRECT3DDEVICE10HOOK_H_

#include "../graphics/includes.h"
#include "../hook/FW1FontWrapper.h"
#include "../hook/BeaEngine.h"
...
#endif
```

Also, I think is weird you have the same variables declared in both the .h and .cpp file:

```
HookContext *presenthook64;
ID3D11Device *pDevice = NULL;
ID3D11DeviceContext *pContext = NULL;

DWORD_PTR* pSwapChainVtable = NULL;
DWORD_PTR* pDeviceContextVTable = NULL;

D3D11PresentHook phookD3D11Present = NULL;
D3D11DrawIndexedHook phookD3D11DrawIndexed = NULL;
D3D11ClearRenderTargetViewHook phookD3D11ClearRenderTargetView = NULL;

IFW1Factory *pFW1Factory = NULL;
IFW1FontWrapper *pFontWrapper = NULL;

bool firstTime = true;
void* detourBuffer[3];
```